# std::is_array returning true when it should be returning false?

Tags: c++, std

I've created a static assertion in order to make sure I don't call my helper function which creates a unique pointer (it's part of my memory debugging code).

The problem I face is that the assertion seems to go off when `T` isn't an array.

**The function:**

```
template<class T> n::c_uptr<T> mem::make_unique() {
    static_assert(std::is_array_v<T>, "T must not be an array.");

    return n::c_uptr<T>(nullptr, [](T * pv_object) { });
}
```

**The function call:**

```
private: a_row_uptr iv_row = n::mem::make_unique<a_row>();
```

`a_row` is an abstract class, and I've also tried with `!std::is_abstract_v<T> && std::is_array_v<T>`.

```
3>class_method_definitions\mem.h(122): error C2338: T must not be an array.
3>class_definitions\db\a_result.h(6): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<n::db::a_row,std::function<void (_Ty *)>> n::mem::make_unique<n::db::a_row>(void)' being compiled
3>        with
3>        [
3>            _Ty=n::db::a_row
3>        ]
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: How do I delete this question? Obviously I must invert the test so that when the evaluation is false, it will fire off the error.

Comment: Is there not a button labelled "delete"?

Comment: No, I probably have too low reputation for that.

Comment: Look at the bottom of your post: **share** **edit** **close** **delete** **flag** You will need to click **delete**

Comment: Well, there we go. World's smallest links with low contrast. Either way, I may not delete since too many has been active in the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I need to invert the condition statement, as it will fire off the error when the evaluation is false, rather than true.